# .htaccess redirectMatch except base

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have this redirect working beautifully:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/stories/(.*)$ /$1`

What I need to happen is happening; all sub-pages of /stories/ (eg: example.com/stories/my-story/ redirects to example.com/my-story/). Great.

Now, I need the base url of example.com/story/ to redirect to example.com/blog/ I've tried the following before and after the redirectMatch:

`Redirect 301 /stories/ http://dev.explorersedge.ca/blog/`

No go.  Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: `/stories/` or `/story/`? Try this `RedirectMacth 301 ^/stories/?$ http://dev.explorersedge.ca/blog/` If the last slash is required - remove `?`

Comment: It's /stories/ (I know, I know...). It looks like your suggestion would take anything from stories (like /stories/foo-bar) and redirect to /blog/, which isn't what I'm after.

Comment: `would take anything from stories` - nope, did you try it? it is limited to `/stories/` or `/stories`

Comment: No go. Redirects to `/`

Comment: Because you have to put it above your `RedirectMatch 301 ^/stories/(.*)$ /$1`, or rewrite cited rule as `RedirectMatch 301 ^/stories/(.+)$ /$1`

Comment: Yes! Your new redirectmatch rule worked with the /blog/ rewrite coming after it.  If you add this as an answer I'll certainly select it as correct.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following redirect, acting on exact `/stories/` or `/stories` URLs (not required presence of the `/` is defined by `?` in regexp),

```
RedirectMacth 301 ^/stories/?$ http://dev.explorersedge.ca/blog/
```

above your existing `RedirectMatch`, or below it, but modify, in that case, existing to

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/stories/(.+)$ /$1
```

so, that it will work only for `/stories/` with at least one symbol after it (otherwise `.*` matches 0 or any number of symbols).